# how to know vendor id, device id, serial number of internal CD/DVD writer?

Tags: usb, dvd

we have the usb-devices command to know the external CD/DVD writer details like serial number, vendor id, device id. But i want to know the same for internal CD/DVD writer.

Comment: Under what operating system?

Comment: @Gilles In RHEL

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "lshw" command, in Debian/Ubuntu it is in a package with the same name. It provides you with tons of detailed information.

Or try "lsscsi" (for instance `lsscsi -c`).